# HTML changes made from JavaScript functions are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to update an `h1` header with an id of `"prompter"`. The value is received from an input with `id="userText"`. I'm able to alert the value just fine.

But when I try to use the .html method in jquery, the change appears for barely a split second before reverting back to the original title. Any ideas what's going on here?

My .js file:

```
var stepper = function() {
    alert (str);

    //why doesn't this line say displayed
    $("#prompter h1").html(str);
}

$(".go").click (function() {
    str = $("#userText").val();
    stepper();
});
```

EDIT (Simplified -- But H1 still only changes momentarily)

From my .js:

```
$(".go").click (function() {
    var str = $("#userText").val();
    $("#prompter").html(str);
});
```

From my HTML:

```
<form class="col s12 ">
    <div class="row">
       <input placeholder="Paste text here" id="userText" type="text" class="validate"></input>
       <label for="userText">What you want to read</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn go">Go</button>
</form>
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rqy751u7/)**

Comment: please provide html also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can directly use the `id`

```
$("#prompter").html('new text');
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hz36oos6/8/)**

**Update:**

`Button` that has a type `submit` inside a form will postback

Change the button type from `type="submit"` to `type= "button"` so that it will not postback in which the reason why your text reverted to original

```
<button type="button" class="btn go">Go</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was trying initially. It would work fine when I put it outside the function, but if I want it to respond to a click, the H1 immediately reverts back to the original.

Comment: @JustinEder, I tried your code and it's working fine https://jsfiddle.net/hz36oos6/1/  maybe you have another function that triggers to revert the value

Comment: Your right! It was working. There's something else that's happening in the background. I uploaded my full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/rqy751u7/

I'm not sure what this error means: {"error": "Please use POST request"}

I think I need to add this to my form: <form method="POST">

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here's the live site: http://www.justineder.com/sketches/WIP/SpritzClone/

Comment: Thank you. That was it. Works like a charm!

Comment: you're welcome @JustinEder, you can mark my answer as accepted if it helped, for others to easily find the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

your code is totally incorrect..look below

```
var stepper = function(str) { //access parameter
alert (str);
//why doesn't this line say displayed
//$("#prompter h1").html(str);    //this is incorrect    
$("#prompter").text(str); or $("#prompter").html(str);      //this is correct if your h1 id is prompter

}

$(".go").click (function() {
str = $("#userText").val();   //you are going to call stepper() with var `str`
stepper(str);                 //pass var parameter in function
});
```